# marked extensions is ignored if sent renderer

Tags: javascript, javascript-marked

simply if I used this code the extension is working fine

```
const originalText = '## hello world';
marked.use(gfmHeadingId());
const text = marked.parse(originalText);
console.log('text') // <h2 id="hello-world">hello world</h2>
```

but if I changed it to

```
const originalText = '## hello world';
marked.use(gfmHeadingId());
const text = marked.parse(this.originalText, {
  renderer: new Renderer(),
});
console.log('text') // <h2>hello world</h2>
```

it stop working (the h2 doesn't have the id now)
how to make both work together?

Comment: See: https://marked.js.org/using_pro#custom-extensions-example

Comment: @BrahmaDev I have already seen it, it's unrelated, I don't want to create an extension but to use one along with a renderer

Answer (score 0):

answer from GitHub https://github.com/markedjs/marked/discussions/3061#discussioncomment-7411454

```
marked.use({renderer: new Renderer()});
marked.use(gfmHeadingId());
const text = marked.parse(this.originalText)
```